# TypeError: Ok is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a `js` file in this file i have multiple class :

```
class ApiResponse {
  constructor(statusCode, success, message, data) {
 
  }

  Send(res) {
    res.status(statusCode).json({
      message: this.message,
      data: this.data,
      statusCode: this.statusCode,
      success: this.success,
    });
  }
};

module.exports = class BadRerquest extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات نا موفق") {
    super(ResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST, false, message, null);
  }
};

module.exports = class Ok extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد") {
    super(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, true, message, null);
  }
};
```

and i have a `BaseController` i use the `Ok` class :

```
 const {
  OkObjectResultPager,
  BadRerquest,
  OkObjectResult,
  Ok,
} = require("./../../core/api/ApiRespose");

Ok(res) {
   return new Ok().Send(res);
}
```

and i have a `RoleController` , this controller inheritance the `BaseController` and i need to use the `Ok()` :

```
 module.exports = new (class RoleController extends BaseController {
  /***
   * Create Role
   */
  async CreateRole(req, res, next) {
      const role = new Role({
        name: req.body.name,
      });
      role.save();
      return this.Ok(res);
  }
  
})();
```

but when i create a Role it show me this Error :

`(node:10256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Ok is not a constructor`

**whats the pronlem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: `Ok(res) { return new Ok().Send(res); }` I don't think this is even valid. You should be getting an error but I'd expect a different one, not "Ok is not a constructor". What is that code supposed to be doing?

Comment: can you post the base controller code ? There seems to be a problem in that file. Not sure what `Ok(res) {
   return new Ok().Send(res);
}` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export multiple classes from your js file you have to use `exports.Ok = ...` or export an Object containing the references to your classes.

```
class BadRerquest extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات نا موفق") {
    super(ResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST, false, message, null);
  }
};

class Ok extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد") {
    super(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, true, message, null);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  BadRequest: BadRequest,
  Ok: Ok
}
```

Comment: You can omit keys like `module.exports = {
  BadRequest,
  Ok
}`

Answer (score 1):

If this is a function that uses Ok class `Ok(res) {return new Ok().Send(res);}`, it should have `function` keyword before like `function Ok(res) {return new Ok().Send(res);}`, but you will have error because you have your class named Ok and should change function name.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix some issues in your code:

```js
class BadRerquest extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات نا موفق") {
    super(ResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST, false, message, null);
  }
};

class Ok extends ApiResponse {
  constructor(message = "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد") {
    super(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, true, message, null);
  }
};

module.exports = { BadRequest, Ok };
```

`new Ok()` should wrapped in parentheses:

```js
Ok(res) {
   return (new Ok()).Send(res);
}
```

```js
class RoleController extends BaseController {
  /***
   * Create Role
   */
  async CreateRole(req, res, next) {
      const role = new Role({
        name: req.body.name,
      });
      role.save();
      return this.Ok(res);
  }
  
};

module.exports = new RoleController();
```